# Casted Type (TypeScript) Not Being Honored When Using As Key

Tags: typescript

I'm parsing a CSV and want to convert the rows to objects. It looks something like this:

```
function dataToObjects<T extends SomeBasicObjectType>(data: string[][]): T[] {
  const [rawHeaders, ...rows] = data
  const headers = rawHeaders as Array<keyof T>

  const dataAsObjects = rows.map((row) => {
    const dataObject = Partial<T> = {}

    row.forEach((dataPoint, idx) => {
      // TypeScript is fine with this next line
      const header = headers[idx] as keyof T

      if (!header) {
        // throw some error
      }

      // Below presents the type error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'
      dataObject[header] = dataPoint
    })

    return dataObject
  })

  return dataAsObjects
}
```

Tried to keep the example code as simple as possible (and included the point of error as a comment) so forgive me if it's not quite perfect. As you can probably tell, this sample is also derived from me trying to attack the problem as much as possible (ie. casting types where you otherwise wouldn't want to).

You can try this code (I believe exactly as it is) as on the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to see the error.

Comment: dataPoint is always a string. What if dataObject has fields that aren't strings?

Comment: Well `dataObject` will be whatever it's set to there, but I presume you mean what if `Partial<T>` doesn't? That's a fair question, this is one of those instances where I'd like to explain to TS what I know is happening. As a dev, the expectation would be that you know you're using this to go from CSV data directly to an object. The Types that would be passed into `T` would be explicitly to describe data being transformed from a CSV. In my project, I have tests written around ensuring that isn't violated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OP Solution**

Certainly open to ideas for how to most appropriately solve this problem. Examining how DB clients cast the results of queries where TS would similarly have no way of confirming the results are an expected type.

In the meantime, the following suffices:

```
row.forEach((dataPoint, idx) => {
  const header = headers[idx]

  if (!header) {
    // throw some error
  }

  dataObject[header] = dataPoint
})

// Cast to `unknown` prior to casting as `T`
return dataObject as unknown as T
```

Not convinced this is ideal-enough, but it works in a pinch.

Comment: This seems OK to me, to be honest. Typescript ultimately can't tell if your dynamic object matches a rigid type, so you need to at some point assure TS that it matches. This is what things like [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) are formally for, but typeguards are essentially just fancier casts in the end.

Comment: Thanks @y2bd, I'd missed Type Guards, that looks closer to optimal at least. Looks like that page is deprecated, going to find out if there's an alternate approach they recommend as a result.

Comment: That page might be deprecated but type guards definitely aren’t.